# Why are dex files different for different buildvariants of an android project

Tags: android, dex

I have 2 build variants for an Android application. When I compare the 2 apks using APK analyser, i see ~2.5% difference in the multiple dex files. Whereas the code is same for both the build variants. The only difference these variant have is differential app icon and a different boolean value injected via gradle.

I am unable to find the reasons for this difference.

On the other hand, if I use the same build variant to produce 2 apk's by passing the differential boolean flag as a command line parameter to the gradlew command, APK analyser reports 0 differences in the dex files.

Comment: Do they have the same package name?

Comment: You could use baksmali to disassemble both dex files, and then diff the 2 output directories, to see what the differences are.

Comment: @lelloman Yes they have the same package name

Comment: Is the boolean variable used in if statements? If yes the compiler optimizes the code path and removes unreachable code. Therefore the source code is same but the byte code not.

Comment: I have the same question about this problem. I built 5 times on same project, the 1st and the 3rd are the same but they're different than the other. I wonder if this is about compiler's multi-thread or optimization process.